# gRPC issue on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: tensorflow, grpc

While running a TensorFlow test related to gRPC(`//tensorflow/core/debug:grpc_session_debug_test`)
I get following error:

```
    self.server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'server'
```

This appears only on Ubuntu 17.10.
Works fine on Ubuntu 16.04

I have installed following:

```
pip install futures grpc flask-socketio
```

Is there some issue with gRPC on 17.10?
Has anyone faced this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html

My guess is that you have pip install-ed grpc, and not grpcio